# Can i use Id in DAI IMA SDK instead of video Url and adTag Url in android

Tags: android, imasdk

DAI IMA SDK in android uses adTag Url instead of ID as fetched from sample apps provided by google from
"https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/7298842?hl=en".
"https://github.com/googleads/googleads-ima-android/releases/tag/3.6"

While in iOS and ROKU, DIA IMA SDK uses ID to fetch adTag Url. Can we fetch adTagUrl from ID through DAI IMA SDK in android also? Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer: "https://github.com/googleads/googleads-ima-android-dai"
Here example is given of ima-SDK using DAI